# How to use self as delegate to different UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

Context: I have two functions inside my controller that both present a UIImagePickerController with delegate=self

I should do different actions with the image received based on which method spawned de picker

In android I can set a requestCode that behaves like a unique request identifier so when the result comes in delegate function (in this case func imagePickerController) i can differentiate it and i know what to do with it

I don't seem to find anything to differentiate inside delegate function "imagePickerController" so I know which picker caused to method to be called

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add a variable in your `self`.

```
var currentPickerId : Int?
```

Then when you set the delegate:

```
picker.delegate = self
currentPickerId = 1
```

And in your delegate method:

```
switch currentPickerId {
    case 1: // Do whatever you want
    case 2: // And so on
    default: break
}

// And don't forget to reinit the id, you never know... ;p
currentPickerId = nil
```

Comment: yes i wanted to do something like this but isn't there a more elegant method to pass data when i present the picker?

Comment: I'm afraid you can't simply do that. Anyway you can "cheat" by using `restorationIdentifier` variable which can be used for restoration purposes. So you can set a specific value for each. But I highly recommend **not** to use something like that. Another way, would be to create an helper class managing pickers and storing the correct context.